# Why Is accuracy so different when I use evaluate() and predict()?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, classification

I have a **Convolutional Neural Network**, and it's trying to resolve a classification problem using images (2 classes, so binary classification), using **sigmoid**.

To evaluate the model I use:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

path_dir = '../../dataset/train'
parth_dir_test = '../../dataset/test'

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                    rescale=1./255,
                    validation_split = 0.2)

test_set = datagen.flow_from_directory(parth_dir_test,
                                        target_size= (150,150),
                                        batch_size = 64,
                                        class_mode = 'binary')

score = classifier.evaluate(test_set, verbose=0)


print('Test Loss', score[0])
print('Test accuracy', score[1])
```

And it outputs: [image]

When I try to print the classification report I use:

```
yhat_classes = classifier.predict_classes(test_set, verbose=0)
yhat_classes = yhat_classes[:, 0]

print(classification_report(test_set.classes,yhat_classes))
```

But now I get this accuracy: [image]

If I print the **test_set.classes**,  it shows the first 344 numbers of the array as 0, and the next 344 as 1. Is this **test_set** shuffled before feeding into the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add a `shuffle=False`. The code that work is:

```
test_set = datagen.flow_from_directory(parth_dir_test,
                                        target_size=(150,150),
                                        batch_size=64,
                                        class_mode='binary',
                                        shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your model is doing just fine both in "training" and "evaluating".Evaluation accuracy comes on the basis of prediction so maybe you are making some logical mistake while using model.predict_classes().Please check if you are using the trained model weights and not any randomly initialized model while evaluating it.

---

what "evaluate" does: The model sets apart this fraction of data while training, and will not train on it, and will evaluate loss and any other model's metrics on this data after each "epoch".so, model.evaluate() is for evaluating your trained model. Its output is accuracy or loss, not prediction to your input data!

---

predict: Generates output predictions for the input samples. model.predict() actually predicts, and its output is target value, predicted from your input data.

---

FYI: if your accurscy in Binary Classification problem is less than 50%, it's worse than the case that you randomly predict one of those classes (acc = 50%)!